# Error while installing maven 3 on cent os

Tags: java, maven-3

I am trying to install maven3 on the centos.

I download the maven from the official [download page](http://maven.apache.org/download.html).

```
wget http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz
```

Its downloaded to the system. But when I run the command for unzip the code.

```
tar -xvf apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz
```

I got the error

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I check on net for the error but is not help in my case.

Comment: Your URL is not the download but a page that let's you select a mirror.

Comment: I suggest you open http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz and see what you are downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you have downloaded is an HTML page, containing a list of mirrors from which to download the actual content. This is why it can't be unzipped.

Try using one of the links on the page like follows.

http://apache.cs.utah.edu/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

The same page also has the md5 checksums did you check your downloaded file against it?